# addTarget on UIButton not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, addtarget

I have a UIView class

```
class FloatingView  : UIView {
    lazy var floatingButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_add_circle_white_36pt"), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor().themePurple()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews(){ addSubview(floatingButton) }

    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        super.didMoveToWindow()

        floatingButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        floatingButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        floatingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        floatingButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked (){
        print("Clicked..")
    }
```

Added this to view by

```
let floatingButton = FloatingView()
view.addSubview(floatingButton)
```

I've also specified the constraints for the floating view .

[image: Screenshot of button]

The button got added to view as expected but the "buttonClicked" function  not invoked when the button is clicked . The  fade animation on the button when clicked is working though.I've tried UITapGesture but not working .

I've update the class as below

```
class FloatingView{
    lazy var floatingButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_add_circle_white_36pt"), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor().themePurple()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    private var view : UIView!

    func add(onview: UIView ){
        view = onview
        configureSubViews()
    }

    private func configureSubViews(){
        view.addSubview(floatingButton)
        floatingButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        floatingButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        floatingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        floatingButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender : UIButton){
        print("Button Clicked")
    }
}
```

And in controller

```
let flButton = FloatingView()
flButton.add(onview: view)
```

I'm trying to create a floating action button [like this](https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton). I'm not sure whether I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: What is `view` in `view.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor`?

Comment: your code looks great, it should work, what about safearea? try running it in iPhone 6s

Comment: Check the view hierarchy in the UI debugger if there is any other view over UIButton.

Comment: Where does the button get added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: @trungduc view is just self  . Ive updated the code . I've removed all constrains and just use frame to view the button ,everything works except the the addTarget

Comment: @PPL   I've tried with just frame instead of constrains still didnt work

Comment: @vacawama  From the init() i've update the code please check

Comment: Your button has a size of 60x60, but its superview has 0 width and 0 height because you didn't specify a frame when you created it with `let floatingButton = FloatingView()`.

Comment: @vacawama i've specified few constrains for floatingView in view controller     `floatingButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor ).isActive = true
        floatingButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        floatingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        floatingButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: floatingButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: @sayooj - your code works fine for me as-is... Is it possible you don't have the Console open in the Debug Pane, so you're just not seeing the `print("Clicked..")` output?

Comment: @DonMag No consoles . It works when  I  add the same button and target function directly to  view controller instead of the custom view class .

Comment: @DonMag Ive updated the code . Please let me know whether  i'm doing right or not .

Comment: @sayooj - I put up a simple project on GitHub with your code, and the button tap results in "Clicked.." being output to the debug console. Take a look - see if it works for you: https://github.com/DonMag/SayoojFLoatingButton

Comment: Thanks a lot  @DonMag . This project works . I'll try to  update mine accordingly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow fixed it by setting the constrains from within the custom class to its superview rather than from the controller.

```
func configureSubviews(){
    if let superView = superview {
        superView.addSubview(floatingButton)
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: circleSpanArea).isActive = true
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: floatingButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: floatingButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        floatingButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        floatingButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        floatingButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        floatingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change the action to

`action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:))`

and the function to

`@objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton){..}`

Comment: Try instead of action to add a tapGestureRecognizer with action

Comment: No need to send sender in buttonClicked @sayooj your codes is working

Comment: @PPL Tried with and without sender